# text field mandatory when a check box is checked in Visualforce Page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am working in Visualforce where I created Checkbox fields "Rejected" on VF Page and have Text field "Rejected Comments" as mandatory.

Can anyone help me out in this issue to achieve it.
My VF Page is below.

```
<apex:page controller="ApproveTimeSheetController" lightningStylesheets="true">
    <style type="text/css">
        .inputcell {width:80px;text-align:center;}

        .myFormStyle {
            background-color:#7492B1;
        }

        #customers {
            font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 100%;
        } 

        #customers td, #customers th {
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            padding: 4px;
        }

        #customers tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #eaebef;}

        #customers tr {
            height: 40px;
        }

        #customers tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

        #customers th {
            padding-top: 5px;
            padding-bottom: 5px;        
            background-color: #a9c2d6;
            color: white;
        }
    </style>
    <apex:form id="timesheetform" styleclass="myFormStyle" rendered="{!!PageInError}">
        <script>
        window.onload = function confirmDisbaled(ifchecked, id1 ,id2) {
            document.getElementById(id1).disabled = ifchecked;
            document.getElementById(id2).disabled = ifchecked;
        }  
        function confirmDisbaled(ifchecked, id1 ,id2) {
            document.getElementById(id1).disabled = ifchecked;
            document.getElementById(id2).disabled = ifchecked;
        }
        </script>
        <apex:slds />
        <div style="padding: 20px;" >
            <div class="slds-page-header">
                <div class="slds-page-header__row">
                    <div class="slds-page-header__col-title">
                        <div class="slds-media">
                            <div class="slds-media__figure">
                                <span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-standard-opportunity" title="Approve Timesheet">
                                    <svg class="slds-icon slds-page-header__icon" aria-hidden="true">
                                        <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/assets/icons/standard-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#work_type_group" />
                                    </svg>
                                    <span class="slds-assistive-text">Forecast</span>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="slds-media__body">
                                <div class="slds-page-header__name">
                                    <div class="slds-page-header__name-title">
                                        <h1><span class="slds-page-header__title slds-truncate">{!Title}</span></h1>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <p class="slds-page-header__name-meta">Approve Timesheets</p>
                            </div>
                            <br/>
                            <a href="/{!ParameterId}">Back to Project</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br/>
            <apex:pageBlock title="Date Selection" id="DateSelection">
                <table width="100%">
                    <COLGROUP width="40%"></COLGROUP>
                    <COLGROUP width="40%"></COLGROUP>
                    <tr>
                        <td><apex:outputLabel value="Week Start" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<apex:inputField value="{!fakeWeek1.Week_Start_Date__c}" /></td>
                        <td ><apex:commandButton action="{!Previous}" value="<<"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;<apex:commandButton value="Refresh" action="{!Refresh}"/> &nbsp;&nbsp;<apex:commandButton action="{!Next}" value=">>" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </apex:pageBlock>
            <br/>
            <apex:repeat value="{!TimeSheetsByMembers}" var="member">
                <apex:pagemessages id="ErrorMessages" />  
                <apex:pageBlock title="{!member.TeamMemberName} ({!member.Role})">
                    <apex:outputpanel rendered="{!member.NoTimeThisWeek}">
                        <div style="color:red;"><b>NO TIMESHEET ENTRIES FOR THIS WEEK</b></div>
                    </apex:outputpanel>
                    <apex:outputpanel id="Timesheets" rendered="{!not(member.NoTimeThisWeek)}">
                        <table padding="30px;">
                            <tr><td  style="text-align:right;">  
                                <apex:commandButton value="Approve All" action="{!ApproveAll}" rerender="timesheetform">
                                    <apex:param name="index" value="{!member.TeamMemberid}" assignTo="{!SelectedMemberId}"/>
                                </apex:commandButton>
                                </td></tr>
                        </table>
                        <br/>
                        <table padding="10px;" id="customers">
                            <COLGROUP width="7%"></COLGROUP>
                            <COLGROUP width="12%"></COLGROUP>    
                            <COLGROUP width="12%"></COLGROUP>    
                            <COLGROUP width="7%"></COLGROUP> 
                            <COLGROUP width="5%"></COLGROUP>
                            <COLGROUP width="20%"></COLGROUP>
                            <COLGROUP width="5%"></COLGROUP>
                            <COLGROUP width="5%"></COLGROUP>
                            <COLGROUP width="20%"></COLGROUP>
                            <COLGROUP width="15%"></COLGROUP>
                            <!--headers-->
                            <tr class="dbrow">
                                <th>Date</th>
                                <th style="text-align:center;">Function</th>
                                <th style="text-align:center;">Type of Work</th>
                                <th style="text-align:center;">Hours</th>
                                <th style="text-align:center;">Billable</th>
                                <th>Comments</th> 
                                <th style="text-align:center;">Approved</th>
                                <th style="text-align:center;">Rejected</th>
                                <th>Rejected Comments</th>
                                <th>Click to Edit</th>
                            </tr>    
                            <apex:repeat value="{!member.Times}" var="time"> 
                                <tr>
                                    <td><apex:outputText value="{!time.TimeDate}"/></td>
                                    <td style="text-align:center;"><apex:outputText value="{!time.timerecord.Function__c}"/></td>
                                    <td style="text-align:center;"><apex:outputText value="{!time.timerecord.Type_of_Work__c}"/></td> 
                                    <td style="text-align:center;"><apex:outputText value="{!time.timerecord.Hours__c}"/></td>
                                    <td style="text-align:center;"><apex:outputText value="{!time.timerecord.Billable__c}"/></td>
                                    <td><apex:outputText value="{!time.timerecord.Comments__c}"/></td>   
                                    <td style="text-align:center;">
                                        <apex:inputcheckbox id="apprvchk" value="{!time.Approved}" onchange="return confirmDisbaled(this.checked, '{!$Component.rejectchk}');">
                                            <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!uncheckRejected}" rerender="theBlock"></apex:actionSupport>
                                        </apex:inputcheckbox> 

                                    </td>  
                                    <td style="text-align:center;">
                                        <apex:inputcheckbox id="rejectchk" value="{!time.Rejected}" onchange="return confirmDisbaled(this.checked, '{!$Component.rejectchk}');">
                                            <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!uncheckApproved}" rerender="theBlock"></apex:actionSupport>   
                                        </apex:inputCheckbox>
                                    </td>  
                                    <td><apex:inputText value="{!time.timerecord.Rejected_Comments__c}"/></td>  
                                    <td><apex:outputlink value="/{!time.timerecord.Id}" target="_blank">{!time.timerecord.name}</apex:outputlink></td>  
                                </tr>
                            </apex:repeat>
                        </table>
                        <br/>
                        <table padding="30px;">
                            <tr><td style="text-align:right;">
                                <apex:actionStatus id="submitstatus">
                                    <apex:facet name="start"> 
                                        <img style="opacity:1.0;" src="{!$Resource.SavingGif}"/>
                                    </apex:facet>
                                </apex:actionStatus>   
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                <apex:commandButton value="Submit" action="{!SaveCheckboxes}" rerender="Timesheets,ErrorMessages" status="submitstatus">
                                    <apex:param name="index2" value="{!member.TeamMemberid}" assignTo="{!SelectedMemberId}"/>
                                </apex:commandButton>
                                </td></tr>
                        </table>
                    </apex:outputpanel>
                </apex:pageBlock>        
            </apex:repeat>
        </div>
    </apex:form> 
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this with actionRegion

```
<script>
function textField(myCheck,inputId){
if(myCheck.checked){
    document.getElementById(inputId).style.display = 'block';
}
else {
    document.getElementById(inputId).style.display = 'none';
}
}
</script>
<apex:pageBlock>
<apex:pageBlockSection>

<apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
<apex:outputLabel value="checkbox"/>
<apex:actionRegion>
    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!something}" onchange="textField(this,'{!$Component.inputId}')"/>
</apex:actionRegion>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

<apex:inputText id="inputId" value="{!someString}" style="display:none;" required="true"/>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
```